# How can I achieve action in UlLabel displaying Terms of service , privacy policy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a `UILabel` displaying `NSAttributedString` for Terms of service and privacy policy. How Can I achieve Tap gesture with in the range of "Terms of service" and "privacy policy".

I want to push new view controller when user taps on "Terms of service" and "privacy policy".

Thanks

[image: Action in Terms of service and privacy policy]

Comment: Prefers a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel`. A `UILabel` is not done for user interactions. It can be changed to do so, but that's not it's first purpose. You can look for your issue (UILabel + Touch) or look for `UITextViewDelegate` methods (one detect when user tap on a link).

Comment: The answer in the "duplicate" is correct, although it's much simpler to use UITextView and its `shouldInteractWith` delegate method

Comment: add a button over your label having same constraint as UILabel. Make button backgroud clearColor and remove its text. add action to button. or you can also use just button and set its attributedtitle.

Comment: UITextView delegate  func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange)  works for me.